# Open a txt file using C# and read the numbers on the file

Tags: c#

How can I open a .txt file and read numbers separated by enters or spaces into an array list?

Example:

[image]

Now what I want to do is to search (for 1 2 9 ) and send to the console.

I have tried a lot of code but nothing seems to work :(

This is my current code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace Padroes
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {


            // Open the text file using a stream reader.
            const string FILENAME = @"Example.txt";


                List<List<int>> data = new List<List<int>>();

                string inputLine = "";
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

                while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                    if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                    {
                        List<int> inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();

                        data.Add(inputArray);
                    Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
                    }
                }
            }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

With this code this is my output:

[image]

Now what can I do to search only for (  1 2 9 ) and send only the 1 2 9 to console ?

Comment: What is the code that you have tried

Comment: Posted the code I tried .

Comment: You know whats a fun read for this kind of situation ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @NadeSticker, please add the code to your question, and not as an answer, I have edited your question to add the code from the *answer*.

Comment: See `string.Split` and `int.Parse`

Comment: what I want to do is that .
search in my file for (int 1 2 3 4 ) then write to console the answer

Comment: The code you posted does not look remotely related to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Isn't this the same as your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236006/open-a-txt-file-using-c-sharp-and-read-the-numbers-on-the-file

Comment: the code I posted search for ("abc" ) in the txt file I just wanto to search (int 1 2 3 4)

Answer (score 0):

I belive this would do the trick.. I simply used  a `StreamReader` and looped throught each line.. Im not sure if i got the part of the condition 100% but if i do it should look somthing like this :

```
      StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"test.txt");
      string line= file.ReadLine();
        while(line!=null)
        {
            if (line.Equals("5 8 1 7"))
                MessageBox.Show(line);
               line = file.ReadLine();
        }
```

Goodluck.

Comment: thank you for your answer Im going to test or ajust the code to my program and see if it works

Comment: @NadeSticker alright. i would appreicate if you could mark it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<int>> data = new List<List<int>>();

            string inputLine = "";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            while((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                if (inputLine.Length > 0)
                {
                    List<int> inputArray = inputLine.Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();

                    data.Add(inputArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks man I tried your code and I got a great output but now I want to add the search for a specific numbers ( 1 2 9 ) can you help me with that ?

Comment: Try this : if(Enumerable.SequenceEqual(inputArray, new List<int> {1, 2, 9 })){};